# can't ping ubuntu server after upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, ping

I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 from Ubuntu 14.04 on my remote server. I can not ping/ssh to the server. I sent someone to physically have a look into the server and got to know it can't ping other servers connected in the same network. What might have happened and what is the solution? Sorry, since I don't have physical access to the server, I could not put many details. I will add more information needed slowly.

Some messages that I got during login:

```
aufs au_opts_parse:1155:dockerd[1344]: unknown option disperml

run_parts: etc/update-motd.d/50-landscape-sysinfo exited with return code 2
```

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thank you, will check it out!